# For loop python - by year and groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, geopandas

New here. I have rainfall data that shows seasonal totals from 1990-2011 for 24 rain gauges (i.e.'RG1, 'RG2'). I did a spatial join to associate each rain gauge with the watershed it's in. I'm interested in looking at these yearly - I did one for 2008, where it shows me the season rainfall totals for each watershed. How do I write a for loop that iterates over the data for each year (1990-2011) and puts it all in one dataframe? Any help is appreciated - thank you!

```
year2008s = rainfall_watershed.loc[rainfall_watershed['year']=='2008'].groupby('WATERSHED_NAME', as_index=False)['inches'].sum()
```

[image: screenshot of dataframe]

Comment: Will you please provide a text-based version of your dataframe, with `print(df.head().to_dict())`?

Answer (score 1):

Group by year and WATERSHED_NAME rather than only by WATERSHED_NAME?

```
out = rainfall_watershed.groupby(['year', 'WATERSHED_NAME', as_index=False)['inches'].sum()
```